# return dates not included in database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Develop winform application using visual basic 2013 and connect SQL database (server 2014)
Below tables included in database
(dates in format Month-Year)

[image]

My question is:

Need to generate SQL Query return months not paid for member

So for memID 1 result must be Empty

For memID 2 result must be:

```
4-2016
5-2016
11-2016
4-2017
9-2017
```

OR

If I need to redesign my Table (columns) to make this query easier, What is suggestion about table and query

Comment: Fix your data structure. You're storing your dates as strings, that's a terrible approach. Use `date` data type and store it as year-month-1st day of the month. Or alternatively - have two separate fields to store year and month.

Comment: data stored as dates, this picture designed in word just to focus required columns and remove others.

Comment: You need a calendar table (a table with every date listed in it) and then you need to outer join to this table

Comment: @Nick what is your suggestion about calendar table and outer join query? take in mind huge amount of data we already have 50000 member data since 1980, and this number will grow up in the future

Answer (score 0):

For each member, you can generate all the months from the first date and then determine the ones that done exist.  Assuming that you change the formats of the columns to be the first day of the month:

```
with months as (
      select memid, firstpaymentdate as dte
      from members
      union all
      select memid, dateadd(month, 1, dte)
      from members
      where dateadd(month, 1, dte) < getdate()
     )
select memid, dte
from months
where not exists (select 1
                  from paymentdetails
                  where fromdate >= dte and todate <= dte
                 );
```

Note:  This works as is for up to 100 months for each member.  After that, you need to set the maximum recursion option.